# When do eclipses occur?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

[This site](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:World_Interactions) lists many Dawnguard add-on random encounters that occur "during an eclipse."

Why do I want to know? I'm trying contract Sanguinare Vampiris ASAP. In an earlier play-through, I came upon a vampire attack at Pelagius Farm, on my way to Whiterun from Riverwood. I manipulated the vampire into afflicting me. I'm trying to get this to occur again, but another vampire isn't spawning there. Perhaps I came upon it during an eclipse? I was also level 33 at the time rather than level 1, but I've buffered up to level 26, so that may matter too. Now that I think about it, I could possibly get a vampire to attack Riverwood too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe "eclipse" in that context means that the sun was temporarily blotted out because the player character shot at it using [Auriel's Bow](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Auriel%27s_Bow) and [Bloodcursed Elven Arrows](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bloodcursed_Elven_Arrow). You can get Auriel's Bow as a reward for the quest, [Touching the Sky](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Touching_the_Sky).

Comment: I think there are also natural eclipses.

Comment: @Ids I've searched and can't seem to find anything about natural eclipses in Skyrim. [Searching UESP wiki](http://uesp.net/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&search=eclipse&fulltext=Search&ns134=1&ns146=1&ns0=1&ns118=1&ns120=1&redirs=1&profile=advanced) only lists a few articles about Dawnguard DLC related eclipses, which leads me to believe that the eclipses mentioned in the 'Random Encounters' UESP wiki article are the ones caused by Auriel's Bow (a Dawnguard DLC weapon).

Comment: Yeah, also searching right now. I seem to recall some list of when the eclipse was. But not sure.

Comment: Can't find anything. You are right. I stand corrected.